# Array slowing down program in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in CodeIgniter, I am running this code.

With it my PHP code doesn't finish. The view absolutely refuses to load. It just shows loading.

`$gen1` is an array on the server side and I pass it with

```
$data['gen1']=$gen1;
$this->load->view('name',$gen1);
```

On the client side

```
 <?php for($i=1;$i<=count($gen1);$i):?>
           <a href="#" class="linktoquestion"><?php echo $i;?></a>
 <?php endfor;?>
```

`$gen1` is an array of only 3 objects.

Each object has around 5 or 6 fields.

Comment: Aaah... My bad. Stupid error. Should have seen that :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look closely at your `for` loop. `$i` never changes, so it'll be an infinite loop.

You probably want

```
 <?php for($i=1;$i<=count($gen1);$i++):?>
```

Comment: Correct!!.. Embarassing..... :-D . Nice catch